# How to capture MySQL syntax error in Bash, $? doesn't work on me

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I wish to find a "Bash" way to capture error when there is a SQL error.
For example, in my bash script, I run below SQL with obvious error.
I found a few links suggest using "$?", I tried but it always returns 0 since the commands has been successfully executed. Is there anyway that I can capture error in Bash when the SQL statement has error? Thanks !!

```
sql="SELECTXX FROM DUAL"

result=$(mysql -h ${host} -u ${username} -p${password} --skip-column-names --silent --execute="${sql}")
```

The result:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECTXX FROM DUAL' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

`$(command)` captures the output of command.

What you want is:

```
mysql ....
result=$?
```

`$result != 0` indicates and error

Comment: Thanks. But the issue is  $result always returns 0 on me even I have syntax error in my SQL statement. Does anyone actually captures non-"0" status for sql with syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of your command. This will redirect standard error to standard output and then you will get the error into the result variable. Otherwise you will only get the standard output.  Like this:

`result=$(mysql -h ${host} -u ${username} -p${password} --skip-column-names --silent --execute="${sql}" 2>&1 > /dev/null)`